# How can I show the Settings window from the command-Line to select which icons are shown in the Notification Area?

Tags: windows, command-line, settings, system-tray

In Windows 10 x64, when I run this command-line:

```
explorer shell:::{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
```

...then I get this older window to select which icons are shown in the Notification Area (Tray-Area):

[image]

But I need this newer Windows 10 Settings window to select which icons are shown in the Notification Area (Tray-Area):

[image]

How can I directly show this specific Settings window from the command-Line?

Comment: You can get one click away from it with `start ms-settings:taskbar` (then *select which icons*). I am not aware of a direct shortcut, and I don't see one listed in the [ms-settings:personalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#personalization) documentation.

Comment: One click away is not that what I need.

Comment: Is it true that Microsoft forgot to provide a direct shortcut to this settings page?